# Mockito set private property

Tags: properties, mockito, setter

I have a small problem with Mockito. Let's say I have this code :

```
MyObject object = mock(MyObject.class);
System.out.println("PROPERTY 1 BRUT VALUE : " + property1Value);
object.setProperty1(property1Value);
System.out.println("PROPERTY 1 VALUE BEFORE STUB : " + object.getProperty1());
when(object.getProperty1()).thenReturn(property1Value);
System.out.println("PROPERTY 1 VALUE AFTER STUB : " + object.getProperty1());

PROPERTY 1 BRUT VALUE : 150.0
PROPERTY 1 VALUE BEFORE STUB : 0.0
PROPERTY 1 VALUE AFTER STUB : 150.0
```

The problem is that my object property is not set directly. I have a method in MyObject that uses it and it always return 0. It is not possible to set directly an object property if it is mocked ?

Found nothing on the documentation on this point.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1** : Here is the method in MyObject that uses the property set by Mockito

```
public Double getProperty1X2() {
    return 2 * property1;
}
```

This method returns 0 in my tests, even if I set the property value. Maybe because it is using the field directly and not the getter ?

Comment: You're mocking MyObject. So the code it uses internally shouldn't be relevant at all. What is the class under test? Why does the class under test care about the value of a private field of MyObject?

Comment: I'v edited my question with the method. You're right, the internal behavior of my class shouldn't be a problem in the test, but the property value is not set...

Comment: It returns 0 because the method `getProperty1X2` has not been stubbed. If your test relies on these two methods, they should both be stubbed. If not stubbed, they return a default value (0). A mock doesn't use the code of your class. It overrides all its methods, and for each of the methods, returns what you tell it to return. If you want the real code of MyObject to be executed, why do you mock MyObject?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean here. But the problem is that I want to use my method getProperty1X2 as it is defined in the class and stub others (methods that need to retrieve data from the database for example)

Comment: Then you want a spy, or a partial mock. They're both described in [the documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html) (points 13 and 16)

Answer (score 1):

You can check my answer on this discussion:-

[Is it possible to invoke mocked object's method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618956/is-it-possible-to-invoke-mocked-objects-method/24693781#24693781)

The key point for you is:-

```
when(object.getProperty1()).thenCallRealMethod();
```