# Is it possible to invoke mocked object's method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito

I have, for example, this class:

```
public class A {
    private List<String> list;

    public A(B b){
        list = b.getList();
    }

    public List<String> someMethod(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

I want to unit test `someMethod` without invoking constructor. I use *reflection* to set `list`.

The problem is that I don't want to create `B` class object and I cannot mock it since it will cause NPE.

So my question is:

How to test `someMethod` without calling constructor of `A`? Is there any way to mock class A and doesn't lose posibility to call methods?

Creating constructor with zero arguments is not a solution.

***Note:*** I **don't** want to change any part of A class. I'm asking if it is possible to perform this test without adding or changing anything in A class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test class A without calling it's constructor by Mockito. Not sure if I really understand your requirement but the following codes work for me.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        A a = mock(A.class);
        when(a.someMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();
        List<String> listInA = new ArrayList<String>();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(a, "list", listInA);
        assertThat(a.someMethod(), is(listInA));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm impressed. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should mock out the collaborators to your class -- that means that you can create an instance of the class being tested, and pass in mocks, configured to 'do the right thing' when it's methods are called.

In your example, you want to create a mock B, and use it like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class myTest {
  @Mock private B b;

  public void someMethod() {
    doReturn(new ArrayList<String>()).when(b).getList();
    A a = new A(b);
    assertEquals("result", a.someMethod().get(0));
  }
}
```

Comment: You may need to actually return something in the arraylist, depending on the further behavior of A, but given your example, this should work.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't want to mock `B` at all. The real `A` constructor is using multiple methods from B and it's fileds. They are used to set `A` fields so I didn't wan't to mock everything in `B`. I guess I am not able to achieve anything else. Of course your answer is correct.

Comment: If it's correct, it'd be good to get a tick. Now, if you want to, you could always create an instance of B as a spy (using @Spy) -- this will allow you to mock out only the methods you need to. However, this is a constant problem when writing tests -- to write a unit-test you /must/ mock/stub collaborators, otherwise your test is fragile.

Answer (score -2):

> I don't want to create B class object

Add a constructor or factory method which doesn't require a B.

```
public A(B b){
    this(b.getList());
}

/* package local */ A(List<String> list){
    this.list = list;
}
```

By making the constructor package local it can be accessed by unit tests in the same package.

> How to test someMethod without calling constructor of A?

You can use

```
A a = theUnsafe.allocateInstance(A.class);
```

but this is not recommended unless you have no other option e.g. deserialization.

Comment: You should never, under any circumstances, write code into your production classes that will be used only by tests. You should test your classes in production like scenarios, and you should check only production-like code-paths.

Comment: _Creating constructor with zero arguments is not a solution._ I'm guessing OP feels the same way about this approach.

Comment: @EngineerDollery +1 I agree, this is the ideal, but not all projects are ideal.